# Swift - Wrong date format (JSON .NET)

Tags: .net, json, swift, api, alamofire

I'm trying to make a API call with Alamofire in my app, but I get a strange error.

```
'There was an error deserializing the object of type Tucson.Geocaching.WCF.API.CreateTrackableLogRequestV1. DateTime content '\/Date(1452942271163+0500)\/' does not start with '\/Date(' and end with ')\/' as required for JSON.'
```

On the [Website of the API](https://api.groundspeak.com/LiveV6/geocaching.svc/help/operations/CreateTrackableLog) it say the date format must be like this: `"\/Date(928174800000-0700)\/"`

My code:

```
postTBLog("GSYCNP", text: "Test", date: "\\/Date(928174800000-0700)\\/", logType: 48)

func postTBLog (code: String, text: String, date: String, logType: Int) -> Bool {
    if let apiKey = apiKey {
        let url = "https://api.groundspeak.com/LiveV6/geocaching.svc/CreateTrackableLog"
        let parameters:[String : AnyObject] = ["AccessToken":apiKey, "TrackingNumber":code, "UTCDateLogged": date, "Note":text, "LogType":logType]

        Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON).responseString { response in
            print(response)
        }



        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

I have already tried different things but nothing seamed to work. I would be very happy if you could help me, thx.

Comment: What things have you tried? Have you tried just giving it the exact example from the API documentation? Have your tried giving it something deliberately wrong for the leading/trailing part and then the date? Have you tried not escaping the backslash?

Comment: @bill I've tried the example from the API and other date formats but nothing worked.

Comment: add single quote Date('....')

Comment: @JoeHuang Doesn't work either

Comment: You need to be explicit about "nothing worked". Always the same message? Did you try non escaping? Is there an exact full example in the API documentation, and have you tried that, in isolation from your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I turned `"\\/Date(928174800000-0700)\\/"` to `"/Date(928174800000)/"`